# ASP.NET MVC Cannot redirect after HTTP headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this warning in IIS can it be related to requesting cookies from the browser or how I am using `Response.Redirect`? From some research I see suggestion that I need to add `Response.Buffer = true;` Is that correct?

Code

```
    public ActionResult GetTemplateById(string TemplateId)
    {    
        string loginUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["loginUrlCottTemplateId"];
        Request.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ev", "sJlp+HNulad4GaX2RCjjlQ=="));
        if (Request.Cookies["customerguid"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["customerguid"];
            string cookieValue = cookie.Value;
            cookieValue = cookieValue.Replace("%2D", "-");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect(loginUrl + TemplateId);

        }

        if (!AuthenticationRep.IsUserValid(Request))
        {
            return Redirect(storeProductLink);

        }
        var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(fm.FileData);
        return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/pdf");
    }
```

IIS exception

> Exception message: Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.
>
> Thread information:
>   Thread ID: 213
>   Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL.NET v4.5
>   Is impersonating: False
>
> Stack trace:
>
> at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ASP.NET MVC application you are redirecting using `Response.Redirect(someurl)`.
When used in an ASP.NET Web Forms application, any code after `Response.Redirect(someurl)` is never executed. However when you use the same in ASP.NET MVC the code execution will continue even after sending the redirect response. To know why, go through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rickandy/response-redirect-and-asp-net-mvc-do-not-mix).

Your code is trying to redirect two times in the same ActionResult, through -

```
Response.Redirect(loginUrl + TemplateId);
```

and

```
return Redirect(storeProductLink);
```

and I believe that is throwing this error.

Please change `Response.Redirect(loginUrl + TemplateId)` to `return Redirect(loginUrl + TemplateId)` and check if  this fixes your problem.

Comment: would adding a return be better?  return Redirect(loginUrl + TemplateId);

Comment: The problem is not in how you are returning. The problem is in where you are returning. In your case, depending on conditions, both Response.Redirect and return Redirect are getting called. You have to make sure that in any condition you return redirect response only once.

Comment: Would it be better to use a elseif

Comment: @Jefferson I have edited my answer and provided reasoning for the same. Do let me know if it works.